# Redux-Form can't do a remote submit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to use this functionally http://redux-form.com/6.6.1/examples/remoteSubmit/ as follows:

On **`index.js`** I declare a function that closes my modal component (that contains the redux form), and a function that dispatch the submit action (for remote submit). Both are passed via props to AccountScene (a presentation component).

On **`layout.js`** `AccountScene` component pass via props the two functions to **`CreateAccount.js`** (final component that contains the form).

At last component, I need that when I press `acceptButton` on `UTModal` component this submit the form (and in this test case, close modal).

I tried passing this config parameter to redux-form decorator: `onSubmit: submitModal`, but throws  `error: 'submitModal' is not defined`.

Thanks in advance.

---

### index.js

```
class AccountsContainer extends Component {
  state = { modalIsOpen: false };

  handlePress = () => {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: true });
  };

  handleModalClose = () => {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: false });
  };

  submit = values => {
    this.props.dispatch(submit('createaccount'));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <AccountScene
        onCreateAccount={this.handlePress}
        modalIsOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
        closeModal={this.handleModalClose}
        accounts={this.props.accounts}
        submitModal={this.submit}
      />
    );
  }
}

AccountsContainer.propTypes = {
  accounts: accountPropTypes().accounts
};

const mapStateToProps = store => ({
  accounts: store.account.accounts
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AccountsContainer);
```

### layout.js

```
function AccountScene({ onCreateAccount, modalIsOpen, closeModal, accounts, submitModal }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <SecondaryTopbar
        titleText={i18next.t('accounts:accounts')}
        titleIcon={icon}
        iconAltText={i18next.t('accounts:accounts')}
      >
        <UTButton base onPress={onCreateAccount} green type="submit">
          {i18next.t('accounts:addAccount')}
        </UTButton>
      </SecondaryTopbar>
      <AccountList accounts={accounts} />
      <CreateAccount modalIsOpen={modalIsOpen} closeModal={closeModal} submitModal={submitModal} onSubmit={closeModal} />
    </div>
  );
}

AccountScene.propTypes = {
  onCreateAccount: PropTypes.func,
  modalIsOpen: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  closeModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  accounts: accountPropTypes().accounts
};

export default reduxForm({ form: 'createaccount' })(AccountScene);
```

### CreateAccount.js

```
let CreateAccount = props => {
  const {closeModal, modalIsOpen, submitModal, handleSubmit} = props
  return (
    <div>
      <UTModal
        isOpen={modalIsOpen}
        onRequestClose={() => this.setState({ modalIsOpen: false })}
        acceptButton={{ text: 'Add', onPress: () => "I need to submit form here!" }}
        title={'Create account'}
      >
        <UTLabel black>Some text</UTLabel>
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
            <Field
              component={UTFormInput}
              name="accountNumber"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Customer Number"
              validate={[InputValidations.required('Required')]}
            />
          </form>
        </div>
      </UTModal>
    </div>
  );
}

CreateAccount.propTypes = {
  modalIsOpen: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  closeModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default reduxForm({ form: 'createaccount', onSubmit: submitModal })(CreateAccount);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my answer, for the code works i need to do this:

index.js

- Declare handleSubmit function that dispatch(submit('form name'))
- Pass handleSubmit & handleModalClose (for use at onSubmit spot) via props to AccountScene

.

```
class AccountsContainer extends Component {
  state = { modalIsOpen: false };

  handlePress = () => {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: true });
  };

  handleModalClose = (values) => {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: false });
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.props.dispatch(submit('createaccount'));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AccountScene
        onCreateAccount={this.handlePress}
        modalIsOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
        closeModal={this.handleModalClose}
        accounts={this.props.accounts}
        handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

layout.js: pass via props to CreateAccount handleSubmit and onSubmit= closeModal.

```
function AccountScene({ onCreateAccount, modalIsOpen, closeModal, accounts, handleSubmit }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <SecondaryTopbar
        titleText={i18next.t('accounts:accounts')}
        titleIcon={icon}
        iconAltText={i18next.t('accounts:accounts')}
      >
        <UTButton base onPress={onCreateAccount} green type="submit">
          {i18next.t('accounts:addAccount')}
        </UTButton>
      </SecondaryTopbar>
      <AccountList accounts={accounts} />
      <CreateAccount modalIsOpen={modalIsOpen} closeModal={closeModal} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} onSubmit={closeModal} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Finally on CreateAccount.js

- Receive handleSubmit & onSubmit props
- Use handleSubmit on modal acceptButton.
- Pass onSubmit to redux-form component without onSubmit config on
  decorator.

:

```
function CreateAccount({modalIsOpen, closeModal, handleSubmit, onSubmit}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <UTModal
        isOpen={modalIsOpen}
        onRequestClose={() => this.setState({ modalIsOpen: false })}
        acceptButton={{ text: 'Add', onPress: handleSubmit }}
        title={'Create account'}
      >
        <UTLabel black>Some text</UTLabel>
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={onSubmit} noValidate>
            <Field
              component={UTTextInput}
              name="accountNumber"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Customer Number"
              validate={[InputValidations.required('Required')]}
            />
          </form>
        </div>
      </UTModal>
    </div>
  );
}

CreateAccount.propTypes = {
  modalIsOpen: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  closeModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default reduxForm({ form: 'createaccount' })(CreateAccount);
```

I hope this solution can serve someone else who has a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass your `submitModal` function in to your connected component.  Unfortunately, you only have access to your `submitModal` function inside the scope of `CreateAccount` where you passed it in. In the example you provided, the `submit` function is defined outside of any `react` classes and is imported in to the proper file.  Try putting it in its own file or defining it outside your `AccountsContainer` component and exporting it separately.

You need to make several changes here:

```
import { submit } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import yourSubmit from 'your/path/to/submit';
let CreateAccount = props => {
  const {closeModal, modalIsOpen, handleSubmit} = props
  return (
    <div>
      <UTModal
        isOpen={modalIsOpen}
        onRequestClose={() => this.setState({ modalIsOpen: false })}
        acceptButton={{ text: 'Add', onPress: props.dispatch(submit('createaccount'))) }}
       />
      .
      .
      .

CreateAccount = reduxForm({ form: 'createaccount', onSubmit: yourSubmit })(CreateAccount);
CreateAccount = connect()(CreateAccount);
export default CreateAccount;
```

Comment: Ok, this explains the error message, but can i do that the form are submitted when i press acceptButton on parent UTModal component?

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can.  I'll edit my answer and provide code i think will work

Comment: I'm tried with this but this doesn't works, now throws:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
    at CreateAccount (bundle.js:82241)

Comment: Okay try changing `this.props.dispatch...` to `props.dispatch...`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but breaks again, in this moment: Uncaught Error: You must either pass handleSubmit() an onSubmit function or pass onSubmit as a prop
    at checkSubmit (bundle.js:49787)
    at Form.submit (bundle.js:50220)
    at Form.submitIfNeeded (bundle.js:49913)
    at Form.componentWillReceiveProps (bundle.js:50012)

Comment: You need to create your submit function and import it.

Comment: try changing `onSubmit: yourSubmit` to `onSubmit: (values) => console.log(values)` just to test to see if your app is submitting properly.  If it is, then write your own submit function and replace the console.log

Comment: Not works even with onSubmit: (values) => console.log(values), i think that the problem now is this line: acceptButton={{ text: 'Add', onPress: props.dispatch(submit('createaccount')) }}

Comment: The problem is in your layout.js. you are initializing two forms with the same name.  The form in your layout.js does not have an `onSubmit` handler.  Not sure what you're doing with two forms.

Comment: I have needed include that on layout.js because if i don't put this, app fails and throw

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `AccountsContainer`.

Comment: Change it to `export default AccountScene`. You should never have two forms with the same name, and you're not even using redux form in that component.

Comment: This last fixes the last error, but again throw: You must either pass handleSubmit() an onSubmit function or pass onSubmit as a prop.

I don't understand yet how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Try also importing your submit function in to createAccount and passing it in to the form: `<form onSubmit={yourSubmit} noValidate>`

Comment: Sorry I can't help you any more without having access to the code in a repo

Comment: Stephen, I've found a solution for this and explained here, thanks a lot for your help and goodwill.